# how to quickly show the files of the same directory in vim

Tags: vim

I opened a file in directory A and finished editing. Next I need to open another file in the same directory (A) and show in buffer. Currently I have to type :e directory A, which is really tedious. Is there a way to quickly navigate to the files of current directory? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to install any plugin, you could:

```
:cd %:p:h
```

if you have `set autochdir` in your `.vimrc`, you could save that above line.

then

```
:Sex
```

to open (netrw) a file list under your current directory, you could open file in that split window.

This command might be easy to remember. :)

If you don't want to have any split window, you could type:

`:Ex`

For details, plsease check:

```
:h :Explore
```

this will open the dir/file list in your current window.

If installing plugins is also ok for you.

There are plugins you could take a look, for example:

```
NERDTree
```

or

```
CtrlP
```

Comment: thanks a lot! many choices indeed! BTW, can I know how to close current buffer without collapsing the split window? When I use :bd to delete a buffer the "split" layout is also gone... Thanks!